# Unbound module Camlp4

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I am aware of similar questions on this site but none of them have helped to solve my problem.

I am very new at OCaml and am using the following tutorial about using Camlp4 https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4/wiki/OCaml_code_generation_tutorial

However I get an error on the first line:
`open Camlp4.PreCast`
saying "Unbound module Camlp4"

There is a camlp4.exe file where I have downloaded OCaml so I assumed it was installed. I have tried this both on Windows 8 and Xubuntu

This is the input I am passing to the command line to compile the file:
`ocamlc -o test.exe test.ml`
where test.ml is the file that contains the line with the error

Comment: The bottom of the tutorial seems to give much more compiler invocation than what you're using: >ocamlc -I +camlp4 -pp camlp4of.opt camlp4lib.cma pa_vector.ml camlp4 -parser pa_vector.cmo

Answer (score -2):

You should know that camlp4 is deprecated, you should use [ppx](http://whitequark.org/blog/2014/04/16/a-guide-to-extension-points-in-ocaml/) instead.

If you need to compile an old programs using camlp4, they should have instructions on how to build. Anyway it's very rare to use `ocamlc` directly, you should try [ocamlbuild](https://github.com/gasche/manual-ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual.md) or at least use `ocamlfind`.

Comment: camlp4 is deprecated? ORLY? How one can one use ppx to have modified syntax?

Comment: From camlp4 README: "Camlp4 was part of the official OCaml distribution until its version 4.01.0. Since then it has been replaced by a simpler system which is easier to maintain and to learn: ppx rewriters and extension points." And most big projects using camlp4 (Lwt, Core) are moving to ppx. Jane Street, the largest Ocaml user is converting its code base from camlp4 to ppx: https://blogs.janestreet.com/converting-a-code-base-from-camlp4-to-ppx/ That's what deprecated means.

Comment: One of the latest articles on http://ocaml.org/community/planet/ : http://rgrinberg.com/blog/2016/02/15/scrap-your-camlp4/